# How do I unregister a directory from Java watchservice?

Tags: java, nio, watchservice

I registered a folder to my watchService:

```
path.register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
```

Later on, I want to cancel this registration. I know that I somehow need to tell the watchService which WatchKey I want to cancel. What's the correct function to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the information in the `Watchable` interface javadoc that provides the method to register a `Watchable` object (such as a `Path` instance)

---

**public interface Watchable**

> This interface defines the register method to register the object with
>   a WatchService returning a WatchKey to represent the registration. An
>   object may be registered with more than one watch service.
>   **Registration** with a watch service **is cancelled** by invoking the key's
>   cancel method.

---

So you have just to do :

```
WatchKey watchKey = path.register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
...
watchKey.cancel();
```

Answer (score 3):

The register method returns the WatchKey, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Watchable.html#register(java.nio.file.WatchService,%20java.nio.file.WatchEvent.Kind...)), which has a [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#cancel()) method.