# How do I end/cancel registration from the below code

Tags: java, watchservice

I came a cross some code from:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio2-watchservice

The topic is regisration to a watchService for changes in directory.
What I am missing from their example is *how* to eventually *cancel* from the registration.

I understand (from other answers in stackoverflow, specifically this one: 
[How do I unregister a directory from Java watchservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950919/how-do-i-unregister-a-directory-from-java-watchservice)) 
that I should keep a key that is the output of Paths.register(), but here they did not keep a key.

So, suppose that I do not keep a key - How to cancel registration?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code from the site I mentioned : my lake of understanding is derived from the line starting with: *path.register(watchService....)*

```
public class DirectoryWatcherExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WatchService watchService
          = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));

    path.register(
      watchService, 
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, 
          StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE, 
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

    WatchKey key;
    while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            System.out.println(
              "Event kind:" + event.kind() 
                + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
        }
        key.reset();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use the method `cancel` of `WatchKey`, here's the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchKey.html#cancel())

Comment: thanks @Arnaud Claudel. On which object should I invoke cancel ? on the key that is later taken from watchService.take()?

Comment: I can't tell. You said *So, suppose that I do not keep a key*, you have to decide when you want to cancel it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unregister a directory from Java watchservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950919/how-do-i-unregister-a-directory-from-java-watchservice)

Comment: So we are back to square 1: If I do not keep a key, as in the example, does it mean that cancellation from the registration above is impossible? Really sounds unlikely..

Comment: answer to : _Possible duplicate of How do I unregister a directory from Java watchservice?_ - Look carefully, I already mentioned it in my post and mentioned the situatuin is a bit different...

Comment: To me, not keeping a key means cancelling it. If it's not what you want, then please clarify

Comment: Ok I will try to clarify: In the post we both mentioned we keep a watchKey that is the ruturn value of method register. with this watchKey we later make a cancellation of the registration. But in my post *we do not keep a watchKey*. We later get a hold on some watchkey that is the ruturn value of take() method. Now, considering your answer above I am wondering: Can I use this key (from take() method) for cancellation of registration?